# Python console closes right after opening

Tags: python, windows

Very new to programming, in my Python code I write:

```
print "Test"
```

or

```
print Test
```

and with either of these it opens the console for a split second and closes, is there any function like the "Console.Read();" function in C#?

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: I made a .py file on my desktop.

Comment: If you run the code just by clicking on it, it will execute and complete (causing the window to close). If you execute it from the interpreter or inside another program, the window will stay open.

Comment: open a command prompt to that location and run python file.py. You'll see "Test" in the console.

Comment: Now I get this problem: 'Missing parentheses in call to print.'

Comment: For future reference you can use `input()` to mimic Console.Read()

Comment: @Jesse Sounds like you are using Python 3, so write print("Test") instead.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of `Console.Read()` is:

```
import sys
_ = sys.stdin.read()
```

This isn't very robust, since it only works if the line is processed; an exception can easily bypass it. It also doesn't give you a hint that the program is complete and not just stuck in a loop. Here's a more complete template for Python 3:

```
import sys
import traceback

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except:
        traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info())
    print("Program ended, press Enter to quit.")
    _ = sys.stdin.read(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

With no imports

```
print("Hello")
input()
```

Input is read and discarded.

Python 3.x only.